# Reducing computation time for matrix operation in for loop in R

Tags: r, matrix

For the following two matrices, I would like to find the mean for each column. It is easy to find for a small number of row and a small number of column.

```
  yy=matrix(c(1:40), nrow = 10, ncol = 4)
    tt=c(1:8)
    yy_new=matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol=length(tt))
    yy_new1=matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol=length(tt))
    dim(yy_new)
    for ( it in 1:10){
      for ( tim in 1:8){
        yy_new[it, tim]=yy[it,1]+yy[it,3]*tt[tim]
        yy_new1[it, tim]=yy[it,2]+yy[it,4]*tt[tim]+2
      }
    }
yy_new_mean=apply(yy_new,2,mean) #column wise mean of the first matrix 

yy_new1_mean=apply(yy_new1,2,mean)
```

If the number of column and rows are very large say 10000 rows and 2,000 columns, It is taking too much time to create the matrix which is in the inside loop `(yy_new and yy_new1)`. Can I do do it efficiently so that the computation will not take a long time?

Comment: creating the matrix yy_new[iteration, tim]  takes a long time. Can I get the col means without storing the matrix?

Comment: thanks. I am trying to speed up the calculation of creating the matrix yy_new[iteration, tim] and yy_new1[iteration, tim]

Comment: Can you give an example of how the `yy_new` matrix should look like? Now the code doesn't work because you didn't define `it`. Is that the iteration?

Comment: why not try `apply()` its usually faster. Also, if you want to use for loop then use `foreach()` it works in parallel and is much faster

Comment: Now it should work, I have defined it. @Leo Barlach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [outer](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/outer) to create matrices of the results you want:

```r
yy_new <- outer(1:10, 1:8, function(x,y){
  yy[x,1]+yy[x,3]*tt[y]
})

yy_new1 <- outer(1:10, 1:8, function(x,y){
  yy[x,2]+yy[x,4]*tt[y]+2
})
```

That's much faster than a `for` loop. In general in R you want to avoid `for` loops, as most functions are vectorized.

Comparing both options using `microbenchmark`, it's about 100 times faster:

```
  min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
 6207.115 6601.342 7691.66462 6868.801 7215.776 45110.99   100
   27.152   30.855   50.98553   56.066   61.532   195.35   100
```